# Hover and mouse over simultaneous jquery effects

Tags: jquery

I have a button with a hover effect:

```
$('.donations').hover(function() {
    $(this).find('#donate_expand_top').hide().stop(true, true).animate({
        height: 'toggle'
    }, {
        duration: 200
    });
```

I now need to add a click effect on the same button so that it's touch-friendly. I understand the concept easy enough using `$('.donations').click(function(){...` but the problem is in combining these two effects it doesn't work correctly. As soon as I click on the button, i'm also hovering, so it tries to fire both and neither works.

Is there an easy solution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They way I've handled it:

1. use [modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/docs/) to detect if the user's device is touch enabled.  You can also use any other way of detecting this.
2. apply your hover/click binds accordingly.

Comment: +1 - I think i like this approach better, although it could go in to more detail.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the most elegant solution, but it keeps track of user's interaction with the button and fires the click event on hover:

```
var interactingWithBtn = false;
$('#donate_expand_top').hover(function() {
    if(!interactingWithBtn) {
       interactingWithBtn = true;
        $('#donate_expand_top').trigger('click');
    }
},
function() {
    interactingWithBtn = false;
});

$('#donate_expand_top').click(function() {
    if(!interactingWithBtn)
        interactingWithBtn = true;
    $(this).find('#donate_expand_top').hide().stop(true, true).animate({
        height: 'toggle'
    }, {
        duration: 200
    });
});
```